# Convert multiple JSON files to a single shapefile or geodatabase feature in ArcGIS or Python

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, arcgis-pro, geopandas

I have been querying one feature in Esri ArcGIS REST Service, but because it is a large data, I had to query it several times (1000 features query limit). This results in many JSON files as parts of one that is supposed to be a single feature. Convert from JSON to Feature only allows one JSON. so

> Condition: I have many Esri JSON files
>
> How do I bulk-convert multiple JSON files and merge it into a single shapefile/geodatabase feature?

Is there a single way to do this using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Desktop?

I am familiar with Python (GeoPandas) but not familiar with ArcPy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using the [ArcGIS Python API](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/install-and-set-up/) instead? Instead of getting JSON files, you could query feature layers directly and export them to a GDB all within the same library (this assumes ArcPy is installed in your computer). [More on Spatially Enabled Dataframes](https://developers.arcgis.com/python/guide/introduction-to-the-spatially-enabled-dataframe/) from the ArcGIS Python API E.g.

```
import pandas as pd
from arcgis.gis import GIS
from arcgis.features import FeatureLayer

# if the features are not public and require your login
GIS('https://arcgis.com','username','pw')

flayer = FeatureLayer('your url to a feature layer')
sdf = pd.DataFrame.spatial.from_layer(flayer)
sdf.spatial.to_featureclass(location=r"c:\location\to\your.gdb\flayer");
```

Comment: Oh! it works for one Feature Layer Service, but it doesn't work on my objective feature service! it returns "Error performing query operation (Error Code: 400)", why is that?

Comment: I am not sure what an object feature service is. You can access always access the layer's item by doing `item = gis.content.get('item_number')` and then using `item.layers` to see the layer you want (gis variable will be what is returned from GIS())

Comment: sorry, bad choice of words. I have 2 features service link (point features, and polygon). your suggestion works on point features but what I need is the (polygon) feature service. When I tried it on the (polygon) feature service link it returns "Error performing query operation"

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a recent version of ArcGISPro (i think 2.4 or newer) you can just put the endpoint into many gp tools.

For example the gp copyFeatures tool will copy all features/records from the input to a local fc. Here's what code looks like but you'll want to update the fs variable's path to have correct guid & fc-name.

Below is python code

```
    import arcpy    
    fs = r"https://services1.arcgis.com/{guid}/arcgis/rest/services/{fc-name}/FeatureServer/0"
    arcpy.management.CopyFeatures(fs, r"c:\myproject\x.gdb\fc-name")
```

Comment: Question, why does the "r" has to be in the code? I do have and tried your code. It returns an error: (ERROR: code:500, Error performing query operation, Internal server error.) I've tried several layers and one returns (ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset {url} does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (CopyFeatures).

Comment: hi sutan, python string literals treat "\" as an escape sequence, so "\t" is a tab, and "\n" is a carriage return, etc... When setting windows paths, you end up with a lot of "\", like if you do `x = "c:\temp"`, the value of `x` will be `c:    emp`.  So to avoid "\" being treated as an escape sequence, you can do `x = r"c:\temp"` which tells python to treat the literal as raw string.  For more see https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals